# Git Bash history commands not saving when closed

Tags: bash, git

Before when I installed Windows 10 when I press the arrow down or up button inside Git Bash I get my previous entered commands. But now when I have closed Git Bash i lose all the commands I have ever entered. How do I get this back?

Comment: the so called "history" is a bash feature. see this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488498/bash-history-does-not-update-in-git-for-windows-git-bash) describing a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks fixed it by entering exit. It automatically makes a .bash_history file.

Answer (score 11):

This is a duplicate and has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901227/5243543

Put this in your ~/.bash_profile

`PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`

Comment: You should check the link in this answer, was very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Just enter `exit` inside the Git Bash console. It will add or update a `.bash_history` file.

Comment: Effectively it works, but I don't think is a good solution. Why when we close the window of git bash it doesn't update the .bash_history?

Comment: You only have to do it once though. The next time you close the window it will save.

Comment: I thought also, but if I don't type `exit` it don't save the history

Comment: Or CTRL-D for fast exit also working.

Comment: Observing that I lost my history because of an automatic Windows update & reboot as well :-(